# Highcharts pie get series color in tooltip headerFormat

Tags: highcharts

While I use another Highcharts chart type (column, bar), I can get the color in tooltip headerFormat with {series.color}. But I could not get it with pie chart. I also tried to use {point.color} and it returned nothing.

```
tooltip: {
     borderWidth: 0,
     backgroundColor: "#EBEBEB",
     headerFormat: '<span style="background:{series.color}; color:white;">{point.color}{point.key}</span><br/><br/>',
     pointFormat: '<span>{point.color}{point.percentage:.2f}%</span>({point.y:.2f})<br/>',
     useHTML: true,
     style: {
         padding: 10
     }
}
```

Do we have another way to access color in pie header tooltip? or did I do something wrong? Here's fiddle of the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/k61fotnr/3/

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can access to the original point: `{point.point._propertyName}`

So in your case:

```
headerFormat: '<span style="background:{point.point.color}; color:white;">{point.color}{point.key}</span><br/><br/>',
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k61fotnr/5/

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. This problem made me hate pie chart for few days. Where did you read that? Is it in API reference?

Comment: @esteh use the Source Code ;) `{point}` is reference to the point with values, but stores reference to the original point: `{point.point}`. For example, to get some custom properties, from the options, you can use `{point.point.options.myProperty}`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use rgba format :

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(244, 127, 40, 0.85)'
```

`0.85` is the opacity of your tooltip

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k61fotnr/4/

Comment: I need to get {series.color} value in tooltip's headerFormat, not to change tooltip background color :(

Comment: @esteh Oh sorry, I didn't understand it this way. I'll look for what you want